# Is there any rule of lbw which considers 2.5 meters?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is there any rule which states that leg before wicket is not a violation when the batsman is 2.5 meters from the stumps? I have read the rule about the lbw but there is nothing stating that.

But there is an instance in World Cup 2011 in a match of India where I saw that because the batsman's distance from stumps was more than 2.5 meters, he was given not out.

So if that's the rule why it is not written somewhere?
And is there any marking on the pitch so that the umpire can know that batman is out 2.5 m from the stumps?

Answer (score 5):

The only situation in which 2.5 m comes into play is if the [Decision Review System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umpire_Decision_Review_System) is used. At that point, if the point of impact is more than 2.5 m from the stumps, then (hand waving slightly) the [on-field umpire's original decision is less likely to be overturned](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc_cricket_worldcup2011/content/story/504570.html). Specifically, see section 3.3(i)(iii) of the Decision Review System - Playing Conditions (Appendix 2) from the [standard Test Match Playing Conditions](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/518a6f5d5f88e-Third%20Umpire%20-%20Decision%20Review%20System.pdf):

> With regard to determining whether the ball was likely to have hit the stumps [...] where the evidence shows that the ball would have hit the
>   stumps within the demarcated area as set out above but that:
>   * The point of impact is 300cm or more from the stumps; or
>   * The point of impact is more than 250cm but less than 300cm from the
>   stumps and the distance between point of pitching and point of impact is
>   less than 40cm,
>   the original decision will stand (i.e. not out)

As such, there's no need for any markings on the pitch, as it is determined by the information from the DRS cameras, not by the on-field umpires.

Comment: but it is not written in DRS rules

Comment: Yes, it is. See my edit. What is your basis for saying it is not written in the DRS rules?